# Phan giving problems with built-in JetBrains PhpStorm annotations

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a problem with the new PhpStorm built-in annotations described in https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-4/

This is the code:

```php
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;
#[NoReturn] public function __construct() {}
```

When I now run my Phan static analyser I get the following errors:

> PhanUndeclaredClassAttribute Reference to undeclared class \JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn in an attribute

How can I fix this? Do I have to composer install some lib from JetBrains to have these annotations in my code base?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I fix this? Do I have to composer install some lib from JetBrains to have these annotations in my code base?

Yes, please see https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes

> The attributes are available in PhpStorm 2020.3 and later. They are bundled with PhpStorm so you don’t need to install them separately.
>
> If you are using other static analysis tools and don’t want to get "Class not found" issues, then you might want to add the attributes package to your composer.json as a dev dependency:

```
composer require --dev jetbrains/phpstorm-attributes
```