# PhpStorm attributes and Psalm

Tags: php, phpstorm, psalm-php

I have PHP 8 on my server, and I'm using attributes `JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape` and `JetBrains\PhpStorm\Pure` as PhpStorm suggests.

When I'm running psalm it returning me the following error:

> ERROR: UndefinedAttributeClass - .....:66:7 - Attribute class JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape

I have two questions:

1. How this classes connected to the project? I can not find them in the composer autoloader.
2. How to fix the psalm error. (I can add them to my bootstrap file of the psalm, but I don't know where they are. I found them only in the `/snap/phpstorm/208/plugins/php/lib/php.jar`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691398/783119 for both of your questions. Let me know if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank You! It help.